# With Ember Simple Auth, how do I redirect to a login page if user is on a page they need to be signed in to view?

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

When using Ember Simple Auth, how do I redirect the user to a login page if they are trying to view a page they can only access when they are signed in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just must import `AuthenticatedRouteMixin` in your `Route`

```
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';
```

and use it like this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin);
```

This will make the route (and all of its subroutes) transition to a configurable login route when the session is not authenticated.

More info [here](http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/AuthenticatedRouteMixin.html).